# Scrapy Xpath output empty

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like extract data on this website : http://www.pokepedia.fr/Pikachu
I'm learning the python and how to use Scrapy and my problem is : Why I can't retrieve the data with Xpath ?

My Xpath look good when i test xpath in my browser, it return me the correct value. (Google Chrome)

```
import re
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from stack.items import StackItem


class StackSpider(Spider):
name = "stack"
allowed_domains = ["pokepedia.fr"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.pokepedia.fr/Pikachu",
]

def unicodize(seg):
    if re.match(r'\\u[0-9a-f]{4}', seg):
        return seg.decode('unicode-escape')

    return seg.decode('utf-8')

def parse(self, response):
    pokemon = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]')

    for question in pokemon:
        item = StackItem()
        item['title'] = question.xpath(
            '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/th[2]/text()').extract()[0]
        yield item
```

I want to extract the name of the pokemon in the page but when I use :

```
scrapy crawl stack -o items.json -t json
```

My Json output :

```
[
```

In my console i've this error :

```
IndexError : list index out of range
```

I've followed this tuto : https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/

Comment: as outlined in a provided answer, be careful with trusting any web browsers dev console/xpath viewer, because the document they display is not always the exact HTML that the page produces. Often it will add tags, and fix any broken html. it is often better to download the html of the page directly (simple python script can do) and word from that. Web Scraping is a great tool to learn but keep this tip in mind always, it has bitten me a few times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
question.xpath( '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]/tr[1]/th[2]/text()').extract()[0]
```

The browser adds the *tbody* tags. They are not in the original HTML, that's why scrapy returns an empty file.

PS: you might want to consider using

```
scrapy shell URL
```

and then using

```
response.xpath('...YOUR SELECTOR..')
```

for debugging and testing.

Comment: Works fine in my browser but with scrapy my output is empty. There is a mistake in your answer is /text() and not .text()

Comment: @Quentin I edited my answer, check again, it should work.

Comment: The shell return empty array with your Xpath expression but thanks for making me discover scrapy shell fort test and debug.

Comment: Are you sure? after running `scrapy shell http://www.pokepedia.fr/Pikachu
` and then `response.xpath( '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]/tr[1]/th[2]/text()').extract()[0]` the output should be Pikachu

Comment: Ok, it's work in shell but in browser return me an empty array. do you have download the html content ?

Comment: Here's the thing, the browser interprets the HTML code differently from Scrapy. So you'll often have Xpath selectors that work in the browser but not with Scrapy and the other way around. The reason for that is that the browser tries to fix the HTML code according to some standards, Scrapy doesn't bother. So if your code works in the shell, then it'll work with the scrapper.

Comment: Nice explanation, I understand. For exemple I see browser add tbody in the generate HTML but this code doesn't exist for Scrapy beacuse is generate by browser.

Comment: Exactly. When you have the choice, try to locate items by their class or id, the id. It's the same across all browsers/Scrapy and specifically id is the least prone to change when the website updates its content.